# Why I can't use databinding for TextView textColor?

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have TextView and 
when I bind 
`android:textColor="@{viewModel.theme.primaryTextColor}"`
where  `primaryTextColor` is data class `Theme(val primaryTextColor:String)`

I got this compile error
`Cannot find a setter for \u003candroid.widget.TextView android:textColor\u003e that accepts parameter type \u0027java.lang.String\u0027\n\nIf a binding adapter provides the setter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches."`

as soon as I change `android:textColor ="#FF00000"` it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
@BindingAdapter({"bind:color"})
fun setColor(textView : TextView , primaryTextColor :String ) {
    textView.textColor = (ContextCompat.getColor(textView.getContext(), primaryTextColor)
}
```

and in xml add this line

```
app:color="@{viewModel.theme.primaryTextColor}"
```

Note : primaryTextColor is String if not change accordingly.

Comment: I see your point but I don't understand why if primaryTextColor is string and = "#FF0000" why it can't work and as soon as I explicitly write #FF0000 it works ?